# How can I delete old publication targets in Web 8.5 migrated from 2013sp1?

Tags: publishing, web8.5

I have migrated CMS from 2013sp1  to Web 8.5, I tried running `Clear-TcmPublicationTarget` but, still the old targets are showing when I click any items to publish..

Is there a way I can delete the old items??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Clear-TcmPublicationTarget` doesn't delete the target - it "decommissions the specified Publication Target". Meaning the system forgets that anything was ever published to that target.

Step two is to actually delete the Publication Target and its associated Target Types, which you can do using the API or the UI.

If you wish to do it through the UI, you'll need to enable legacy publishing management through a configuration file as documented on the following page: [Showing the Publishing Management node](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-3F49BCA1-4201-477E-928E-53E2E2143322)

The relevant steps:

1. On the Content Manager server, navigate to the folder `%TRIDION%\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Configuration\`.
2. Open `CME.config` for editing.
3. Find the enablepublishingmanagement element and set its contents to true.
4. Save and close `CME.config`.
5. Restart the Content Manager Explorer Web site.
6. Access the Content Manager Explorer Web site, select the **Administration** tab and confirm the presence of the **Publishing Management** node.

Answer (score 0):

Using the TOM.NET API or the Core Service API, you can decommission a Publication Target; that is, you can delete the Publication Target without explicitly unpublishing its contents.

**Before you begin**

Decommissioning a Publication Target requires System Administrator rights.

**About this task**
Decommissioning a Publication Target is useful if you are working on your Content Delivery infrastructure and are simply removing your Publication Target's server(s). Actually unpublishing all items is potentially time-consuming and unnecessary if the server or servers are removed anyway.

**Procedure**

**Procedure**
**Do one of the following:**

- In TOM.NET, call the PublishEngine.DecommissionPublicationTarget
  method.
- In the Core Service, call the DecommissionPublicationTarget method.

  Refer to the respective API reference documentation for more details on these methods. Effectively, these methods set the publish status of all items on the Publication Target to "unpublished" for that Publication Target.

Delete the Publication Target. If any publish action to that Publication Target occurs before you delete it, you need to decommission the Publication Target again.