# Removing old Publishing Target in Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5

Recently we upgraded Tridion 2011 to Web 8.5. After migrartion we found the old Publication Targets are still there. So using the Powershell script `Clear-TcmPublicationTarget` I tried to decommision the old Publication Target, but I got some time out error.

When I tried to delete the Publication Target from Publishing Management UI, I got one error related to the `SP EDA_SYSTEM_DECOMMISSIONPUBLICATIONTARGET`.

I opened the DB and checked the script, which takes `Publication Target Id` as input and deletes the some records related to particlar `Publication Target Id`.
I executed the stored procedure from database with the Target ID and it took some 8-10 minutes to finish. After that when I tried to delete the Publication Target, it succesfully worked.

So my concern is, if it is safe to execute the stored procedure manually for removing the Publication Target.

Comment: In general I don't think it is supported to manually execute a stored procedure on the CM database. I would suggest to contact Customer Support and validate it with them.

Comment: Completely agree with Bart, please check with Support for better solution. Just for the sake of help do see this if it helps - https://gist.github.com/vikaskumar185/45a52312a34092cbbdf0ee8559e48d72

Answer (score 1):

Please try below two articles and you got answer:

1. https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-11A16F5A-717A-4B07-ABFC-0F1C29A1C82F
2. [How can I delete old publication targets in Web 8.5 migrated from 2013sp1?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16821/how-can-i-delete-old-publication-targets-in-web-8-5-migrated-from-2013sp1)

Comment: I tried the above links . But as the Old publishing queue had the old publication target references. The powershell command took a long time to execute and finally threw a Time out error. For this scenario we first cleared the old publishing jobs , after migration . Once all the old publication target references were removed from the database, we decomminsioned the old targets using the links you provided.

Answer (score 1):

You should not execute Tridion's database code directly. It's not a supported interface, and you could have problems if you ever need help from SDL support in the future.

In this case, getting a timeout the first time, and then such a long execution time on your second attempt, it's quite likely that your database wasn't properly maintained. (There's plenty of documentation and other material about keeping a Tridion database in good running order, so I won't repeat that here.)

If your database's indices and transaction optimiser statistics are in good order, and you still have problems, then I'd suggest taking the problem to support. They can help you to analyse the problem, and if necessary, can authorise specific actions on the database that wouldn't normally be allowed.